# Какой тип у анонимного типа в с#?

Tags: c#

Суть задачи:
У меня есть данные на с#, которые я получаю в результате определенных алгоритмических вычислений. Далее мне необходимо отправить и по сети, на сервер nodejs, на JS объект имел бы такой вид:

```
const test = {a: 1, b: 2, c: "string"}
```

На C# я создал так.

```
new { Id = 1, b = 2, Body = "string" },
```

Допустим я создал такой тип.

Когда передаю его в функцию, типизирую его как object, потом обращаюсь:

Далее передаю в функцию отправки, где обращаюсь к одному из полей, на что получаю ошибку. Как описать такой объект?

```
Send(object a) {
  a.Body;
}
```

И получаю:

```
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Body' and no accessible extension method 'Body' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Как решить?

Comment: Имя типа создается в момент компиляции. Из кода к нему невозможно обратиться. Для решения можно использовать либо generic, либо dynamic, без проверки типов

Comment: Взял dynamic, но там нужна еще библиотека... Что лучше generic или dynamic для этой цели?

Comment: о какой библиотеке речь? Лучше по какому критерию?

Comment: Анонимный тип используется здесь и сейчас. Если тип нужно передать куда-то ещё, то его следует задать явно.

Comment: Начать следует с того - зачем вам анонимный тип в строго типизированном объектном языке? Если уж так хочется не заводить отдельный тип, то просто используйте кортеж, например.

Comment: То есть мне лучше использовать структуру для этого? Мне нужен тип данных на подобии объекта в JS или асcоциативного массива в php.

Comment: Приведи конкретную задачу которую ты хочешь решить. Не зная что конкретно ты делаешь нельзя сказать, как лучше это сделать

Comment: @Lasna Для этого опишите - а что ещё вы делаете с этим объектом, кроме того, что передаёте его в функцию? В чём смысл его?

Comment: Я создаю объект из более чем 10 полей, например `{a: 1, b: 2, c: "string"}` оборачиваю в json и отправляю по сети. Не зная, какой тип подобрать под это - выбрал анонимный тип.

Comment: что значит _Я создаю объект из более чем 10 полей,_? Поля известны заранее? Как именно оборачиваешь в JSON? Где в этой последовательности действия находится вызов функции `test`?

Comment: Добавь всю необходимую информацию непосредственно в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Заранее известны. Не знаю, как их описать. Разве что классом.

Comment: @Lasna. что с ответами на остальные вопросы из комментария?

Comment: У тебя провал в логике между "создаю объект" и "отправляю по сети". Зачем тебе внутри функции `Send` обращаться к полю объекта? Просто сериализуй весь объект и проблемы нет

Comment: `Не знаю, как их описать. Разве что классом` - именно так

Comment: @Grundy, там в send выбираются ид и отправляются на них циклом, обращаться нужно.

Comment: @Lasna, что значит _выбираются ид и отправляются на них циклом_?

Comment: Сделай цельный, минимальный пример, того, что у тебя происходит.

Comment: @Grundy да не нужен здесь никакой минимальный пример. Я дал совершенно очевидный ответ на очень простую проблему. Через анонимный тип в другой метод не проехать так чтобы пользоваться членами класса. Ну только через `dynamic`, что само по себе ужас и костыль. Поэтому единственное верное решение на основе текущего вопроса - в ответе. Что тут еще приводить? Ответ уже даже принят. И меня бесит, когда ты минусуешь мои ответы без объяснения причин.

Comment: @aepot, при наличии XY проблемы в вопросе, верным решением может стать не костыль с добавлением ненужного класса, а изменение общего подхода ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ А узнать какую проблему на самом деле хочет решить автор, по предоставленной информации, нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вы используете анонимные типы? C# - строго типизированный язык, описание классов здесь норма.

```
public class MyMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

```
public void Send(MyMessage message)
{
    string body = message.Body;
}
```

```
Send(new MyMessage { Id = 1, b = 2, Body = "string" });
```

Comment: смотря какая задача, анонимные типы тоже уместны в своем месте. Не вижу связи между строгой типизацией и необходимости везде лепить классы где это даже неуместно. Но с вашим ответом все равно согласен в части использования класса.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, как я справлялся с подобной задачей. Вы делаете условный запрос приводя его к виду `List<a'>`, а затем передаете вашу переменную

```
select new 
{
    abnId = _abn.Id,
    abnName = _abn.Name,
    contactId = _contact.Id,
    contactFIO = _contact.F + " " + _contact.I + " " + _contact.O,
    abnMail = _contact.Email
}).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.abnId).ToList();
```

Comment: Можно и FirstOrDefault() использовать